# Is it necessary for a login-shell to create utmp entry?

Tags: ssh, login, su, who

My observation:

1. If I open a new terminal *(gnome/lx)*:

   - New **/dev/pts/X** is used
   - `who` does not lists these
   - First character of `echo $0` is not `-`, so its not a login-shell.
2. If I `ssh` into the same machine with the same user

   - New **/dev/pts/X** is used
   - `who` lists these
   - First character of `echo $0` is `-`, so its a login-shell.
3. If I open a new **tty** *(ctrl-alt-Fxx)*

   - New **/dev/ttyXX** is used
   - `who` lists these
   - First character of `echo $0` is `-`, so its a login-shell.
4. If I run `su -`

   - Same **/dev/pts/X** is used *( where `su -` was issued )*
   - `who` does not list these
   - First character of `echo $0` is `-`, so its a login-shell.

Conclusion:

1. Creating a new pty does not automatically create an entry in utmp (?)

Question:

1. If `who` displays the list of currently logged in users, then it should display entries for each login-shell (?). But it does not display entries of root user logged in from `su -`, why ?

**EDIT:** Another thing which I can conclude at this point is: "It has to be a new pty/tty and a login shell, then only a new entry is created  in utmp"

Comment: a ssh login actually also not *always* creates a who entry. *I suspect* the who entry is somewhat created by the first interactive shell of each separate login; never investigated the problem. good question.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro No it doesnt, you are talking about Observation #1 ( not listed under who ). From here if I do ssh (observation #2), new entries are listed in `who`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `who` does not care about login shells, or anything such. It merely dumps `utmp` entries. You can have an entry for non-login terminals; for graphical sessions; for FTP connections (with a completely made-up tty "line" name); for just about anything.

Second, utmp entries are created *manually* – you only get an entry if the program which processes your login calls `pututline(…)`. For example, sshd always does this, terminal emulators *often* do this (but not always), and `su` never does.

(Remember that `su` does not allocate a new pty, so it can't add an utmp entry either – otherwise you'd end up with multiple entries for the same tty, which can confuse a few programs.)