# Different outputs for `w`, `who`, `whoami` and `id`

Tags: users, who, w, whoami

In command line platforms online, like for instance the one on Codecademy, when I run

```
for cmd in w who whoami id
do
    echo $cmd
    $cmd
    echo =========================
    echo "             "
done
```

I get

```
w                              
00:52:54 up 8 days, 14:10,  0 users,  load average: 3.78, 2.98, 2.69      
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT       
=========================                            

who
=========================                                                 

whoami                          
ccuser                          
=========================                              
  
id
uid=1000(ccuser) gid=1000(ccuser) groups=1000(ccuser)     
=========================
```

Note that only `whoami` and `id` output something. When I run the same thing on my computer, I see similar results for all commands.

Why doesn't Codecademy display the user for `w` and `who`? What's different about these commands?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- `id` reports

  - the current credentials of its own process; or
  - the credentials of a named user, as read out of the *system account database*.
- `whoami` reports the current credentials of its own process.
- `who` and `w` report the active login sessions table from the *login database*.

BSD doco notes that `whoami` does a subset of the job of `id`, and that `id` renders it obsolete.

A system does not have to have an active login sessions table.  On Linux operating systems and on the BSDs, if the table has not been created at bootstrap, or has been deleted since, the system will operate without one.  Logging in and out does not implicitly create it on Linux operating systems, moreover.

Furthermore, the table need not be readable by unprivileged users and neither the `who` nor the `w` command will report this as an error.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). *[The Unix login database](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/unix-login-database.html)*. Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). "[login-update-utmpx](http://jdebp.eu/Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/login-update-utmpx.xml)".  *User Commands*.  nosh toolset.
- Lennart Poettering et al. (2018). [`systemd-update-utmp.service`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-update-utmp.service.html).  systemd manual pages.  Freedesktop.org.
- [Is it necessary for a login-shell to create utmp entry?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/388260/5132)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/409036/5132